# How time creates gravity? According to time curve

Tags: gravity, spacetime

How time dilation creates gravity? I'm assuming gravity is not a force(Einstein's words)

Comment: There is a lot more to gravity — at least to the strong gravity of, say, black holes — than time dilation. Time dilation can only “explain” weak gravity, and explaining it that way leaves you unable to understand strong gravity.

Answer (score -3):

In his famous lecture, Nobel Lauriat Kip Thorne referred to what he calls “Einstein’s Law of Time Warps”.   He said, “Things like to live where they age the most slowly.  Gravity pulls them there.   And so as an application, the Earth's mass warps time according to Einstein. It slows time near the surface of the Earth. And this time warp is what produces gravity.”

This might also be related to the principle of least action, whereby any moving object will take the route that requires the least energy.

Thorn showed that mathematically the amount of time dilation required to produce the gravity we see on earth versus a height of 10,000km is one second per century.  Recently, a rocket containing atomic clocks was sent to 10,000km and verified this estimate with great precision.  The tie between time dilation and gravitational potential is confirmed.

This testing also shows why gravity is so weak on Earth.  It is the rate of time dilation that gives rise to the gravity.  Time dilation of only 1 second per century over a distance of 10,000km is very small.  Near the sun, time dilation is greater and gravity is greater, and much greater still near a very large star, where the gravity is much stronger.

Comment: Can you explain little bit more? How time warps produce gravity? Thanks

Comment: I'm chuckling at the downvotes on my post, which simply repeats what a Nobel prize winner has said.  These people must be really smart.   Thorne's lecture is here http://tinyurl.com/5cana3sk at the 10:00 minute mark.   I have found that gravity works like a low pressure system in time.  Just like wind blowing towards the centre of a low pressure system in the weather, a falling object gives up energy by falling into a lower pressure area.  Check out my paper for a full explanation on this idea: http://tinyurl.com/ypu3hbc6